# Videoplayer is not defined in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am new to cordova, I am trying play video in my application .I have used moust video player plugin in my app,but when i run the app getting error as videoplayer is not defined.Please help me out....I am using cordova 6.2.0.,ubuntu os,Google chrome browser to run the app.

```
showVideo: function(letter){
    debugger;
    if(letter ==""){
        letter=site.findLetterToPlayByDefault();
    } 
    site.currentChildLetter = letter; 
    var videoPath = site.getLetterFromDb(letter); 
    var src = null; 
    //app.isLocal() ? "" : cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"www/videos/"; 
    if(videoPath!=null){ 
        src = videoPath; 
    } else {
        app.log("No video set for letter: "+ letter);
        return; 
    }
    app.log("Playing video at : "+ src + " using "+VideoPlayer);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment and your code.

Comment: showVideo: function(letter){
    debugger;
      if(letter ==""){
       letter=site.findLetterToPlayByDefault();
     }
     site.currentChildLetter = letter;
        var videoPath = site.getLetterFromDb(letter);
        var src =   null; //app.isLocal() ? "" :  cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"www/videos/";

        if(videoPath!=null){
         src =  videoPath;
        }else{
    app.log("No video set for letter: "+ letter);
       return;
     }
     app.log("Playing video at : "+ src + " using "+VideoPlayer); Javascript function dor videoplayer